# Using angr as a pure concrete emulator

Tags: angr, emulation

I am able to successfully run my target binary under [Qiling](https://github.com/qilingframework/qiling), an emulator that supplements Unicorn with hooks for system libraries.  I would like to do the same thing under angr.  I don't need *any* symbolic execution, I don't need *any* Symbion: Just simply use angr as an emulator (which it's more than capable of).  How can I tell angr to run everything concretely, but still continue to hook the libs and replace them with angr's sims?

Surprisingly, this turns out to not be simple.  What I found so far:

- https://github.com/angr/angr/issues/200 - A discussion from  6 years ago how to do this
- https://angr.io/blog/angr_symbion/ Symbion, which does something similar, but much more complex: It runs the concrete side externally, interfaces to it via gdb, and syncs periodically with angr